# What is best Git client for Mac Os with my own server?

Tags: macos, git, github

Well, I tried [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) - very useful thing, but I don't want to share my private code with other (sorry folks from github, but there are commercial projects).

Also I tried to deal with [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) - also, awesome thing, and private Atlassian Bitbucket.

But I still couldn't find the client, which can support my own server.
Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't the GitHub client also work with non-GitHub repositories? At least the windows one does.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: actually I didnt found any "Url" field or smth.

Comment: What you are looking for is most likely called "Remotes"

Comment: @ThiefMaster: unfortunately no. only "preferences" where I must enter Git account & pass.

Comment: Here are your options, learn git's command line and use your own server, or use a commercial service and get a GUI... that simple.

Comment: @Jonathan Incorrect.  SourceTree and Tower both work with "personal" git servers.  See my answer below.

Comment: @BraveS You can use github for Mac for your private repos

Comment: In my situation, my company's firewall blocks access to github (even though I have a personal private repo). So, I'm giving Sourcetree - http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ - a go. I think I remember using it before. I've used so many darn clients, it's hard to keep track. :P

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sourcetree certainly supports local git installations, as does Tower.

You're thinking about it wrong.  You're thinking that because SourceTree only asks you about entering credentials for BitBucket, GitHub or Kiln that that's the only type of git server you can use.  That's incorrect.  It has those authentication dialogs for those services because those services provide extra features beyond just git hosting, so a login is required.

In the case of a standard shared repository rather than a commercial service, just do `File->New` and in the clone repository dialog, enter the URL of the shared repository.  If you have already cloned it via the command-line, then click on the "Add working copy" button instead and point SourceTree to where it exists on your disk.

Once you have the repository cloned, you can pull and push from/to the central repository same as you would if you were using the command-line.  All this is true with Tower as well.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Don't know, why I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of the official Git GUI clients

http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Answer (score 2):

I personally use `/usr/bin/git`.

If you prefer to use graphical stuff then have a look at [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) or better latest version on https://github.com/gitx/gitx/releases.

I do not use SourceTree but I would have thought they would support any server - you might want to double-check that.

Comment: Actually, it supports Atlassin Bitbucket, Github, Kiln. I cant use my own server(

Comment: @Sheonna8 Incorrect.  It supports any server.  See my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Posting after 10 years the answer to my question.
For the previous 6 years I've been using

`git-fork`

as GUI for work with git.
It has all necessary capabilities that I needed to this day.
Thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/). But I preferred Terminal.
Source Tree is the most complete GUI app for GIT than I tested.

Looks like the latest version is on https://github.com/gitx/gitx/releases

Answer (score 0):

Consider Git-Cola

`python3 -mpip install git-cola`